# INTERRUPT problems

Tags: assembly, atmelstudio

In Atmel Studio 7 debug mode: Debugging a program written in Assembler.
I have tried to make my serial 0 tx create an interrupt. (UDR0 )

- bit 7 in SREG is set.
- Serial 0 TX com interrupt vector is correct too.
- Serial setup enables interrupt on TX char.
- program sends a char to UDR0.

DOES NOT WORK.

Tried the same with ADC:

- bit 7 in SREG is set.
- Interrupt Enable is activated in ADC- control register A
- ADC Conversion complete vector is set to correct interrupt vector.
- when ADIF goes high, the debugger Screen clears (obviously something happens ), but it never returns to calling point (after RETI).

This raises the question:
*Are the INTERRUPT functions in ATMEL STUDIO 7 (7.1) in some way dysfunctional, or am I using them incorrectly??  (if so: please help).*

Comment: You forgot to specify what chip you use. Also, a text description does not replace code, especially if there may be some subtle thing missing. Post [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about the missing formatting. I used STACKEXCHANGE  very heavily 3-5 years ago, but have forgotten how to format page.  My former question was haw to format  a page/question.   I'll study that intensively later.  And  the Object in question is a ATMEGA 2560 .  MY fault: SORRY !

Comment: The second problem with ACD clearly points to incorrect interrupt handler code. Provide all related source code.

Comment: "PeterPlesnik" -  Thanks , I'll look into that later.   KRis

Comment: To day I know what the problem(s) are. In fact there are 2.  The first problem is, that I NEVER get the proper bausdate. The board is equipped with a 12 MHz crystal and with that crystal correct baudrates are impossible. and the second problem is (due to bad TX-rx rates) it never synchronizes to frameformat, and as a result of that, it never interrupts.  Made a very simple interrupt example in ASM, compiled it , burned it into a 16 MHz 328 and a 12 MHz . The one with the 16 MHz crystal worked like a dream.   PS:  I have ordered 4 new 16 MHz crystals.... )